# Why is my camera motion so jittery?

Tags: c#, mobile, optimization, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have been working on trying to smooth out my camera motion for my game for days and I cannot get it to a reasonable level of smoothness. Are there any corrections to this code that I can make that will improve the smoothness? I have tried the moveTowards() function as well and it didn't help.

```
/**************************** CAMERA MOVEMENT *********************************/

void FixedUpdate () {
            //Do we need to spawn new platforms yet? 
            Vector2 playerHeight = playerTransform.position;
            if (playerHeight.y > nextPlatformCheck) {
                    PlatformMaintenaince (); //Spawn new platforms
            }

            //Update camera position if the player has climbed 
            Vector2 currentCameraHeight = transform.position;

            if (playerTransform.position.y > currentCameraHeight.y) 
            {
            transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(new Vector2(transform.position.x,0.0f), new Vector2(0.0f, playerHeight.y), smooth * Time.deltaTime);
            } 
            else {
                    // If player is too low, gameover.
                    if ((playerHeight.y) < (currentCameraHeight.y - 5.5)) {
                            GameOver();
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Try Time.fixedDeltaTime.

Comment: Update your camera in `Update` instead of a `FixedUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Update function instead of the FixedUpdate. FixedUpdate only gets called after a certain number od frames.

Answer (score 1):

All the camera movement calculations should be carried out in the `LateUpdate ()`, Let `Update()` get the player position and then let camera use that position after that Update calculations.